# How do I center the text in the navigation?

Tags: css

How do I center the text in the navigation [here](http://wholefoodforhorses.com/)?

I tried adding `text-align:center` to #xg_navigation and #xg_navigation ul and no dice.

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `div` and `ul` are automatically expanding to 100% width by default.

You need to set the div to `display: inline-block;` this will make the width the same as its children content.

And then `text-align: center` the parent to center the `div`.

Comment: i would add more of a description but im on my lunch break... its mac donalds thursday today:P

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it in 3 minutes. It says I can't do it now.